How to accurately detect AI-generated images?
There is this website that allows the visitors to upload an image. The website then proceed to detect how likely the uploaded image is AI-generated or Deepfaked.
I would like to know the logics/algorithms/libraries behind it and how it works.

It's a pretty large research field, one can look at some survey to get pointers to the main algorithms e.g. Detecting Multimedia Generated by Large AI Models: A Survey (2024-02).

